# How to get the *full* filepath of a selected file via QFileSystemModel?

Tags: c++, qt, qfilesystemmodel

How to get a filepath via QFileSystemModel?  Selecting via selection model returns just file name, or drive name.

Note, that just file name isn't enough.  Whole filepath is needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On qt website: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html

> `QString QFileSystemModel::filePath ( const QModelIndex & index ) const`
>       Returns the path of the item stored in the model under the index given.

I dont know if this answers your question, else you can give us some code about what you tried / are trying to reach.

Comment: I think it is not working for PySide6. I get this error: "{TypeError}descriptor 'filePath' for 'PySide6.QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel' objects doesn't apply to a 'PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex' object"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using something like this QFileSystemModel::filePath(index).